# cannot preserve values in the textbox after dropdown on change event

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem in preserving the values in the `textbox` after `dropdownlist` selected index changed in asp.net mvc. Below is the code for initiating the dropdown onchange event.

```
@Html.DropDownList("BranchId",null,"Select Branch", new { onchange = "location.href='/User/GetRoles?BranchId='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value" })
```

Аnd the roles dropdown binded with the values, but what i typed in the textboxes just above the branch dropdown get lost.

Please help me.

Regards,
Azeem

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are changing your URL location by using `location.href`. What exactly do you want to achieve? If you need to load certain logic, you might as well bind change event to jQuery function that could load data from the server, and then you do something with that data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#BranchId").change(function() {
        $.getJSON(YourUrlThatReturnsValues, {data: yourparameter}, function() {
           // do some processing here.
        });
    });
});
```

The other option is to use Ajax Helpers instead of Html Helpers. Instead of `Html.DropDownList` you would use `Ajax.DropDownList`.

Comment: My problem is not with the data in the dropdown, my problem is i have textbox which erases the data which i was typed before once the data loaded in the dropdownlist, so i wanted to preserve the data in the textbox when the dropdown postback occurs

Comment: You are thinking in a wrong way. MVC is not Web Forms. There is no concept of Postback in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like that:

```
$(function () {
        $('#BranchId').change(function () {

         var id = $("#BranchId option:selected").val();

         var data = {BranchId: id }; 

            $.get("@Url.Action("User", "GetRoles")", data).done(function(d){
             $('.somediv').val(d.rolename)
           });

    });
```